# Floating button gets visible on screen overlay or on status bar open

Tags: android

I have floating action button in my activity which is animated to a certain position when another floating action button is clicked. And when animation ends that fab alpha value is set to 0. Now when i open the status bar or any dialog the alpha value becomes 1. How to solve this problem??

Comment: You need to post your code here

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Sections named "[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)" may be useful too in the future.